# jOOQ Postgres PERCENTILE_CONT & MEDIAN Issue with Type Casting

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

Coercion of data types does not seem to work within `median()` or `percentileCont()`. Data type coercion works just fine with other aggregate functions like `max()` and `min()`. The Postgres queries that are produced as a result show that type casting is not applied in the final result. Below are the snippets from `jOOQ` and Postgres for reference. As of now, I have no work-around or knowledge of an open ticket for this issue.

Any direction would be much appreciated!

---

### MEDIAN

jOOQ Snippet

```java
selectFields.add(
    median(
            field(String.format("%s.%s", a.getDataSourceName(), a.getField()))
                .coerce(Double.class)) // Seems to not successfully coerce data types
        .as(
            String.format(
                "%s.%s.%s", a.getDataSourceName(), a.getField(), "median")));
```

SQL Output

```sql
select 
  tableA.columnA, 
  percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by tableA.columnA) as "tableA.columnA.median" 
from tableA
group by tableA.columnA 
limit 100;
```

`ERROR: function percentile_cont(numeric, text) does not exist`

---

### PERCENTILE_CONT

jOOQ Snippet

```java
selectFields.add(
    percentileCont(a.getPercentileValue())
        .withinGroupOrderBy(
            field(String.format("%s.%s", a.getDataSourceName(), a.getField()))
                .coerce(Double.class)) // Seems to not successfully coerce data types
        .as(
            String.format(
                "%s.%s.%s", a.getDataSourceName(), a.getField(), "percentile_" + Math.round(a.getPercentileValue() * 100))));
```

SQL Output

```sql
select 
  tableA.columnA, 
  percentile_cont(0.0) within group (order by tableA.columnA) as "tableA.columnA.percentile_0" 
from tableA.columnA
group by tableA.columnA
limit 100;
```

`ERROR: function percentile_cont(numeric, text) does not exist`

---

### POSTGRES -- This works due to type casting

```sql
select 
    percentile_cont(0.5)
    within group (
        order by tableA.columnA::INTEGER
    )
    as "tableA.columnA.median" 
from tableA.columnA 
group by (select 1)
```

https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/module-summary.html

Comment: Not strictly related to your problem, but I recommend you don't use `String.format` for the production of SQL snippets because of the usual SQL injection risk. [Use jOOQ's built in plain SQL templating mechanisms, instead](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/03/04/never-concatenate-strings-with-jooq/)

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Would this also extend to aliases?

Comment: Aliases are quoted by default, depending on your `Settings.renderQuotedNames` setting, so by default, they're safe. [See also this post here](https://blog.jooq.org/2020/04/03/whats-a-string-in-the-jooq-api/). I just noticed, instead of passing a `String` to `field(String)`, you could simply wrap it in `Name` using `field(name(a.getDataSourceName(), a.getField()))`. That should be the best option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not looking for coercion, which in jOOQ-speak means changing a data type only *in the client* without letting the server know. This is mostly useful when fetching data of some type (e.g. `Integer`) despite jOOQ producing some other data type (e.g. `BigInteger`), otherwise. See the Javadoc on [`Field.coerce()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#coerce(java.lang.Class))

> Unlike with casting, coercing doesn't affect the way the database sees a Field's type.
>
> ```java
> // This binds an int value to a JDBC PreparedStatement
> DSL.val(1).coerce(String.class);
>
> // This binds an int value to a JDBC PreparedStatement
> // and casts it to VARCHAR in SQL
> DSL.val(1).cast(String.class);
> ```

Cleary, you want to [`Field.cast()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#cast(org.jooq.DataType)), instead, just like in your example where you actually used a cast `tableA.columnA::INTEGER`.